# Visual Studio 2019 kestrel debug browsing with Chrome switches to port 5000 instead of port 5001

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2019

I created a new MVC Web Application using Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview Version 16.0.0 Preview 4.1. I set the *App URL* as https://localhost:5001 and the *Launch browser* setting to https://localhost:5001/.  It works happily on IIS Express but there's a problem with using Kestrel with Chrome (Firefox is OK).

The console output shows:

```
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

But Chrome is switching to https://localhost.:5000.

In addition this is not occurring if I run the same thing up in Visual Studio 2017 with Chrome.